# In the bootstrap theme the background color of the hover is not completely covering the background

Tags: bootstrap-4, hover

In the bootstrap4 theme, when we hover the icon gray color is applied to the background. But gray color is not completely covering the background. This issue occured in the chrome browser alone.Also,I can reproduce the reported issue in 150% scaling in the system by default. However, if we change the system scaling to 100%, then the issue can be seen after zooming the screen. Also, if we set the browser zoom to 200%, then the issue is not occured. Please refer the below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Sample link: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/textbox/default-functionalities?theme=bootstrap4

Replication steps:

```
1.  Open the attached sample
2.  Go to the Input & Elements textbox
3.  Click or hover the date or upload icon
4.  The hover color not completely covering the background
```

Comment: Hi, it is covering the entire background. Your input field has a border of 1px. The background area falls within the border.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this issue occurring in chrome browser alone.

Comment: I am using Chrome and it seems fine (inside of the border)

Comment: Do you want to cover the entire input's background? And not just the icon section's background?

Comment: Please refer the scaling in the description. Also, I want the background color(gray) to cover the search icon entirely when hover or click on the icon.